# Vue 3 recommended TypeScript TSConfig compilerOptions TARGET setting?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, compilation, vuejs3

This question has puzzled me at several points when using Vue 2 and Vue CLI, and now again with starting a fresh Vue 3.0 beta project.

Even with the currently newest Vue CLI version 4.3.1, when choosing TypeScript option, the boilerplate code you are given has **compilerOptions target** set as **esnext** in `tsconfig.json`.

While [Vue 2 TypeScript Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html) is instructing:

```
# Recommended Configuration
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // this aligns with Vue's browser support
    "target": "es5",
    // this enables stricter inference for data properties on `this`
    "strict": true,
    // if using webpack 2+ or rollup, to leverage tree shaking:
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

Currently [Vue Next repo is using `esnext`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/master/tsconfig.json), although at this point IE11 support is not ready yet (but might not affect this config anyhow)...

**What will be the recommended setting for this compiler target when using Vue 3?**

I'm needing to support legacy browsers down to IE11, but this particular app project has plenty of time until it's initial release to wait for Vue 3's full release.

Comment: The repo you linked explicitly states, *In addition, the current implementation requires native ES2015+ in the runtime environment and does not support IE11 (yet). The IE11 compatible build will be worked on after we have reached RC stage.*

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Estus, care to make an answer out of it?

Comment: @EstusFlask care to make an answer here, so I can reward your bounty!

Comment: Sure. The answer isn't exhaustive for now, this may change in future. But one thing's for sure, you need to pay attention to reactivity to not have problems with IE11 in future.

Comment: Just keep tuning it better later on then :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Vue 3 repository](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next) states,

> the current implementation requires native ES2015+ in the runtime environment and does not support IE11 (yet). The IE11 compatible build will be worked on after we have reached RC stage.

As it was noted, the target of Vue 3 is currently `esnext`, it relies on modern JS features and is currently aimed at the development in evergreen browsers and isn't supposed to be used in production. Vue 3 cannot be usable in legacy browsers even with lower target because it currently relies on proxies which are ES6 feature that cannot be polyfilled.

The project that uses existing Vue 3 build won't benefit from `target` lower than `es2018` which is likely the least common denominator, object spread is among most popular recent additions that is used in Vue 3 codebase and cannot be polyfilled. TypeScript target can be experimentally lowered to `es5` with `downlevelIteration` option enabled for early detection of some compatibility problems.

It's expected that separate versions of Vue 3 will be maintained for legacy (IE11) and modern browsers. The difference is how reactivity is handled because `Proxy` allows for advanced change detection but cannot be implemented in legacy browsers. The project should follow existing guidelines for [Vue 2 reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) in order to be compatible with legacy Vue 3 build.